# How do I move a committed file to shelf in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to remove a file in master that's no longer used, but instead of completely deleting the file I want to keep it in my shelf (so that I may later salvage some bits of code).

Currently I have to:

1. copy the contents of the file to be deleted into Notepad
2. delete the file and commit + push the deletion
3. create a new file and copy over the contents held in Notepad
4. shelve the new file

How can I do this in 1 step?

Comment: What is your "shelf?"  This certainly is not a Git term (though maybe it is a term with your IntelliJ plugin).

Comment: It's an intellij term - I've removed the git tag thanks

Comment: This is a tricky requirement in Git, because once the file has been deleted from the file system, it won't be there unless you check it out again or switch branches.  Honestly, in this situation I would just keep a local copy.

Comment: is it pushed or only committed?

Comment: @PratikAmbani it is both pushed and committed

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this in 1 step?

You can't do this in 1 step. But in fact, you don't need to do this at all.

The file is tracked by git already, so its content will stay in the history after the file is deleted, and there is no need to copy its content somewhere else. If you later need some content of the file - you can get it from git history.

If you want to keep the file in shelve anyway, there is a bit easier way.

1. Use `git rm --cached` in terminal to stop tracking the file in git without deleting it from disk
2. Commit the deletion - the file will stay as Unversioned
3. Select the file from Unversioned list and Add it to git
4. Shelve the addition.